# dynamically change the image of toolbarbutton? -- using Erik Vold's toolbarbutton.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var toolbarbutton = require("toolbarbutton");

var toolbarbutton = toolbarbutton.ToolbarButton({
  id: "annotator_toolbar_button",
  label: "Web Annotator 2013",
  image: self.data.url("stop.png"),
});

toolbarbutton.moveTo({
  toolbarID: "nav-bar",
  insertbefore: "home-button",
  forceMove: false // only move once
}); 

toolbarbutton.image = self.data.url("start.png");// this command
```

I cannot change the image property of Erik Vold's toolbarbutton library for the Firefox addon sdk.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You could use the library [Toolbar Button Complete](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/166563/), which is my fork of toolbarbutton.js.**

## Using the library

You can use this library the same way as the original toolbarbutton.js, but it also has more options and features.

In your main.js file:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var toolbarbutton = require("toolbarbutton");

var button = toolbarbutton.ToolbarButton({
  id: "annotator_toolbar_button",
  label: "Web Annotator 2013",
  image: self.data.url("stop.png"),
});

/* Only move button if installing for first time */
var forceMove = (self.loadReason === "install");

button.moveTo({
  toolbarID: "nav-bar",
  insertbefore: "home-button",
  forceMove: forceMove
}); 

button.button().setAttribute( "image", self.data.url("start.png") );
```

You can find a working example of the library [here](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/167058/). *(Currently it is a little out of date, though.)*

## Installing the Library

**If you are using the add-on SDK on your computer:**

1. Download [Toolbar Button Complete](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/166563/).
2. add it to your `packages` directory. *(Either under your SDK directory or under your add-on's directory.)*

**If you are using the [Add-on Builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org) to create your add-on**:

1. Click the plus button next to your library folder:

   [image: The plus button.]
2. Type in `Toolbar Button Complete`.
3. Click on the Add Library button:

   [image: Add Library Button]

## Updating the Library

The library is hosted on [github](http://github.com) [here](https://github.com/Geek-in-Training/Toolbar-Button-Complete-jplib).

If you are using the [Add-on Builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org) for your add-on, you can simply click the little refresh button when there is an update available.

Comment: thank you man works perfectly, is there more support for the online sdk editor?

Comment: @phyzical Sure no problem! 
I am not sure what you mean by more support. Could you clarify that?